# Litle endian unsigned short in C++ to Big endian signed short in Java

Tags: java, c++, casting, arduino, processing

Just now, I happened to have overcomplicated type conversion (I still do not understand them types perfectly).
I transferred 0 - 1024 values as 4 bytes (int) from Arduino to Processing via serial link. Soon I realised that I can as well send short (2 bytes) to get 2 times faster communication (and I need it very fast).
So this is what I have in C++ on arduino:

```
  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
  unsigned short sensorValue = 0;  
  //Time when I last sent the buffer (serial link seems to need some rest)
  unsigned long last_time_sent = millis();
  //Buffer to save data I've collected
  byte buffer[256];
  //Position in buffer
  byte buffer_pos = 0;

  while(1) {
    //Get 0 - 1024
    sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
    //(Try to) convert Short to two bytes. I don't even which is first and which is last
    for(byte i=0; i<2; i++) {
       //Some veird bit-shifting, all saved in buffer with an offset
       buffer[i+buffer_pos] = (byte)(sensorValue >> ((2-i) * 8));
    }
    //Iterate buffer position
    buffer_pos+=2;
    //Currently, I send the data allways
    if(true||millis()-last_time_sent>30||buffer_pos+2>=255)
      Serial.write(buffer, buffer_pos);
    //Temporary delay for serial link to rest
    delay(50);
  }
```

Now, in Processing, the java code looks like that:

```
void serialEvent(Serial uselessParameter) {
  while (myPort.available() >= 2) {
    //java doesn't allow unsigned variables
    short number = 0;
    for(byte i=0; i<2; i++) {
      byte received = (byte)myPort.read();
      println("Byte received: "+Integer.toString((int)received));
      number |= myPort.read() << (2-i)*8;
    }
    //Save data for further rendering
    graph.add(number);  //Array of integers, java doesn't let me make array of short
  }
  //Clean old data
  while(graph.size()>MAX_GRAPH_SIZE)
    graph.remove(0);

}
```

I think I've something wrong on the arduino side, because I see this in output:

> Byte received: 0
>   Byte received: -1
>   Resulting 2 byte number: -256

Arduino should values send about 681. (I have a 1 digit display to check the values approximately).

Comment: Why don't you just use `htons()` on the C++ side to transfer data in network byte order? BTW, in Java, all numeric primitive types are in big endian order

Comment: I know Java uses Big endian. It's even noted in question title. Didn't know about `htons()`. I'll have to check if both enviroments support it.

Comment: `htons` has existed for nearly as long as C ;)

Answer (score 0):

- On the C++ side, use `htons()` to turn your `s`horts from `h`ost endianness `to` `n`etwork endianness (`htons`: Host TO Network Short).
- On the Java side, read form the socket, write into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`; once you have all the data, wrap this `ByteArrayOutputStream`'s underlying byte array into a `ByteBuffer`.
- Read the shorts using the `ByteBuffer`'s `.getShort()`.

Comment: Is this effective? I'm going to scan hundreds of bytes per second. And Java seems to be very slow itself.

Comment: Oh, no, Java is not slow, this is a super myth.

Comment: You've heard about LLVM, right? Java's JIT has preceded it for 15 years or more

Comment: That myth happens before my eyes ever since (compare minecraft performance and graphic quality with, say, Metro 2033). When I rendered blocks in C++ I had less (no) lags even with my lame and simple code.

Comment: I don't do graphics, I do server stuff -- and there, Java shines

Comment: Well, server stuff is not very performance demanding unless you have thousands of users, isn't it?

Comment: Or even a hundred times that -- that's not the problem. That Java is slow is a myth, period. That it can't do high end graphics like C++ does is because it doesn't have access to the necessary OS primitives.

Comment: @TomášZato: Minecraft may not look visually impressive, but it has a lot of stuff going on behind the scenes.  High-end graphics aren't the only thing that can cause lag.

Comment: Of course. For example, it renders and calculates even invisible (out of sight) items. I used this one, because it is known Java application. And because its written just as effectively as the java itself is effective.